# Using Sparks with Codeigniter dealing with updated sparks

Tags: codeigniter

I just started using [Sparks](http://www.getsparks.org/) with Codeigniter and really like it,  but am not sure the best practices when a specific spark package is updated.

In other words, if I have the spark:  example_spark 1.0.0 and then it is upgraded to example_spark 1.0.1, I think I would then have 2 versions in the sparks directory?

```
Sparks
  -example_spark
    -1.0.0
    -1.0.1
```

Would I then need to go back to my application and replace every case where I had loaded the original spark:

```
$this->load->spark('example_spark/1.0.0');
```

and replace it with:

```
$this->load->spark('example_spark/1.0.1');
```

I suppose the only other way would be to rename the most current version number directory to "current" and also update any dependency information in the spark.info file also to look in the current directory for each of those.

Am I missing something here, or is this basically the way you need to handle things when upgrading sparks?

Comment: I haven't used Sparks, but I would assume that you would need to handle updates yourself for the most part. Either that, or don't put version numbers in your loader paths, but beware of possible compatibility issues. You could map your sparks to a config file with the version numbers to use if you wanted to get freaky with it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I would probably just need to update manually wherever I loaded a specific version.  But, the config file idea is actually an interesting way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparks are designed to work within a specific codeigniter scope(version). Only when the codeigniter versions changes will you then need to update the MY_Loader class and check for spark updates for that version of CI.  Remove the spark versions folder.